# How to extract letter and number sequences from a string in Velocity Template?

Tags: regex, templates, velocity

I've a string like `'LL101-D10'`. I want to extract String before hyphen starting from first numeric digit in Velocity.

Eg - `"LL101-D10" , LLL101DL-D10`
output - `101 , 101DL`

To extract String before hyphen i did as below-

```
#set ($index = $String.indexOf('-'))
#set ($val1= $String.substring(0, $index))
```

But How i can extract other part in Velocity? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)) as you are entitled to the upvoting privilege after reaching 15 rep points. Note you may upvote all the answers that turned out helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a replace operation using the following regex:

```
^[^0-9-]*([0-9][^-]*).*
```

and replace with the `$1` placeholder referring to the contents captured in Group 1.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/68551j/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[^0-9-]*` - 0+ chars other than digits and `-`
- `([0-9][^-]*)` - Group 1: a digit and then 0 or more chars other than `-`
- `.*` - the rest of the string (without linebreaks, if there are line breaks, add `(?s)` before `^`)

Use it like

```
#set ($val1= $String.replaceFirst("^[^0-9-]*([0-9][^-]*).*", "$1"))
```